# cross-plat version of _wfullpath()

Tags: libc, realpath

is there a cross platform version of _fullpath() which is windows specific function? looking for a portable library function for this.

tried realpath() but this is supported for linux and Mac but not for windows.

Comment: std::filesystem::path absolute(const std::filesystem::path& p); from standard c++ library can be used here which is portable for win/linux/macOS.